# How to save and restore stack

Tags: assembly

In an analog-digital mixed circuit simulator the simulator saves its state in certain moments and sometimes want to restore it. The digital device model is in C++ (using fibers). When the analog simulator request a rollback the digital device model should go to a previous state, including setting back the all local variables and EIP. Could you give me some guidelines? The digital device model is in Visual C++. I handle this situation successfully when the digital model is in VHDL. In such case the VHDL model is compiled to x86 assembly.

Comment: First you have to define "state".  The full contents of the stack at a moment in time?  The stack frames above a certain point?  global variables?   Heap variables?   Thread-local variables?   Clearly if you are going to save state, you have to know what all of it is.   I'm a little unclear as to whether you are building a simulator from scratch, or attempting to modify an existing one.  I'm also unclear what the role of fibers is in this simulator.

Comment: I'm modifying an existing simulator (adding SystemC support to an existing Analog-VHDL mixed simulator). In the VHDL case the VHDL model is compiled run time to asm code, the processes are also my own processes, so I can rollback a bit easier. The SystemC case is different because the whole model is compiled to dll with VC++. In the SystemC case I'm saving the signals(they are special SystemC objects) separatelly but I should save/restore the local variables and EIP also. SystemC uses fibers for processes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682661(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Some rutins in SystemC device model dll is called periodically. For example: run_to_time(model, t). I should write two rutins: rollback_at_now(model); restore_rollback(model, t)
Probably I should save all local variables in the fiber (you mentioned some other type variables, I will save later maybe)

Comment: The device consists digital processes (for example logic gate). The fibers are for this sub-devices.